# What is the best platform/solution to develop an app for iOS, Android, and Blackberry?

Tags: android, ios, blackberry

I will be making a database that is offline and online and wondered what I could use to develop apps for Apple's iOS, Android, and Blackberry all in one sweep.  I know Xamarin does iOS and Android, but not too sure how well it will be on Blackberry?  Are there any other solutions or ideas to nudge me in the right direction.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking for developing cross platform app than `Xamrin`, `Ionic`, `Cordova` is defiantly support blackberry but it will be hard for find native plugins for the blackberry like blackberry only supports `web DB`. For `Adobe cordova` it does not support for `blackberry os 7` or less. If you want more information here is [link](http://www.optimusinfo.com/blog/cross-platform-framework-comparison-xamarin-vs-titanium-vs-phonegap/). Hope it helps you...

Answer (score 1):

For cross platform i know appcelerator-titanium SDK. Also AFAIK newest blackberry support to run Android APK. I suggest you better use Native on Android and iOS, and port the APK to Blackberry.